# Keep SQL query general and make it fast

Tags: sql, matlab, accelerate

After finding the right SQL query for my purposes, I realized that my query is slow.

```
WITH temp_table (t_col_1, t_col_2, t_col_3) AS
(
    SELECT col_1 AS t_col_1, col_2 AS t_col_2, col_3 AS t_col_3
    FROM actual_table
    WHERE ID = 100 AND PID = 1245
)
SELECT t_col_1, t_col_2, t_col_3 
FROM temp_table AS t1 
WHERE t1.t_col_2 BETWEEN 1 AND 12541
  AND t1.t_col_1 = (SELECT max(t2.t_col_1)
                    FROM temp_table AS t2
                    WHERE t2.t_col_1 < 15147
                      AND t2.t_col_2 = t1.t_col_2) 
ORDER BY t1.t_col_2
```

The reason, why I use the query in this form is as follows:

1. The SQL query is generated and used within Matlab to fetch data.
2. Depending on the ID, it can happen that columns col_1 and col_2 are interchanged which is why t_col_1 = col_2 and t_col_2 = col_1. In this case the Matlab script replaces col_1 AS t_col_2 and col_2 AS t_col_1.

Is there an elegant way to accelerate the query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the query regarding the max value of `t_col_1` is running for every row as your main query checks the `WHERE` criteria.  Instead you can generate the `max(t2.t_col_1)` value from a sub-query that runs once and then use that variable in your criteria, like this:

```
SELECT PID, t1.t_col_1, t1.t_col_2, t1.t_col_3
FROM
    (SELECT PID, t_col_1, t_col_2, t_col_3, max(t2.t_col_1) AS t_col_1_max
    FROM temp_table
    GROUP BY PID, t_col_1, t_col_2, t_col_3) 
    as t1
WHERE 
    (t1.t_col_2 BETWEEN 1 AND 12541)
    AND t1.t_col_1 < 15147
    AND t1.t_col_1 = t1.t_col_1_max
ORDER BY t1.t_col_2
```

Your code for generating the temp table looks fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, the SQL query above does not work. Could it be, that there is a mistake in the inner SELECT statement? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe one comment more; does your SQL query also works when t_col_1 and t_col_2 are dates? The numbers in my query were only an example.

Comment: @grima ah, I forgot the `GROUP BY` statement.  The inner query should work now.  As to whether it would work with your data if the data are dates, I can answer that better if you give me a sample of your table.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I am now using a simpler approach... To be preceise, I have hard coded two SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

The answer completely depends upon your query optimiser and database statistics, this in turn will be different depending upon your choice of database.

1. Obtain the QEP - query execution plan
2. See where the plan is slow
3. Optimise the query and/or add database statistics and/or add required indices

You can try to tweak the query and may get lucky, but the proper approach is to understand the query plan.

For example, you have no way to know if the 'max' is slow or actual_table could have a billion rows with no index on ID and PID.